# An innodb table deny alter table operation

Tags: mysql, innodb, alter

I use alter table command to add index to a table .
But the command is not executed by mysql.
I find out there are several read operation on the table meanwhile.
When I stop the read table service .  Alter command successfully executed .
So is there any relationship between doing read & alter table ?
How can I execute alter when the table is on reading ?

Comment: Not quite sure what you're asking here, but it's probably better directerd to the [DBA site](http://dba.stackexchange.com) since it pertains to how MySQL's `ALTER TABLE` works.

Comment: thanks . I will post msg there .

Comment: What version?  How big is the table?